# How to present body background image above content

Tags: css, wordpress

i am working on this [website](http://birsmatt.ch/de/) (builted with Wordpress) and i am trying to set this [image](http://birsmatt.ch/de/wp-content/uploads/20picute%2016/04/bg_left.png) as a fixed left background **above** the entire website content.

Via CSS i'm trying this

```
body { 
background-image: url("http://birsmatt.ch/de/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/bg_left.png"); 
background-position: left; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
z-index: 1; 
}
```

...but the `z-index` does not works.

Any tip?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the body is your whole website content. So if you set a background, it will be behind all the content of the body.

You can create a new element inside the body with the size of the body and give that the background you want.

Example:

```css
#background {
  background-image:url('http://birsmatt.ch/de/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/bg_left.png');
  background-position:left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;    /* make it overlap your website content */
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id='background'></div>
  
  <div id='rest of your content'>
    ...
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Or use a pseudo-element to avoid extra markup: `body:before`

Comment: @isherwood - i was thinking the same, but depends on whether or not the OP wants to support older browsers

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you want to set the width to 100%, the div covers the whole page and thus you cannot interact with it (click on links). Set the width to 60px maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/9dhgo1u1/3/

Comment: The question is: how can i create on Wordpress `<div id='background'></div>` this?